# Sum of Printed For Loop in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-playground

For a project, I'm trying to find the sum of the multiples of both 3 and 5 under 10,000 using Swift. Insert NoobJokes.

Printing the multiples of both 3 and 5 was fairly easy using a ForLoop, but I'm wondering how I can..."sum" all of the items that I printed.

```
for i in 0...10000 {
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 { 
        print(i) 
    }
}
```

(468 individual numbers printed; how can they be summed?)

Comment: How would you go about doing this, as a human? Describe the process.

Comment: You can use [the `+=` operator](https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-swift) to add a number to a variable.

Comment: Actually the result is supposed to be 4668.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little walk through about the process. First you will need a variable which can hold the value of your sum, whenever loop will get execute. You can define an `optional variable of type Int` or initialize it with a default value same as I have done in the first line. Every time the loop will execute, `i` which is either `multiple of 3 or 5` will be added to the `totalSum` and after last iteration you ll get your result.

```
var totalSum = 0
for i in 0...10000 {
if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0
{
    print(i)
    totalSum = totalSum + i
}
}
print (totalSum)
```

Comment: Thank you for the walkthrough! My fundamental knowledge has been improved. You are a gentleman and a scholar!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can do it without a repeat loop:

```
let numberOfDivisiblesBy3And5 = (0...10000).filter{ $0 % 3 == 0 || $0 % 5 == 0 }.count
```

Or to get the sum of the items:

```
let sumOfDivisiblesBy3And5 = (0...10000).filter{ $0 % 3 == 0 || $0 % 5 == 0 }.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but please don't give it out so freely. Guide OP through the thinking process that led you to this.

Comment: The question asks for the *sum* of those numbers, not for the count.

Answer (score 1):

**range** : to specify the range of numbers for operation to act on.

here we are using **filter** method to filter out numbers that are multiple of 3 and 5 and then sum the filtered values. 
(**reduce**(0,+) does the job)

```
let sum = (3...n).filter({($0 % 3) * ($0 % 5) == 0}).reduce(0,+)
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you remove downvote please.?

Comment: Great ! but It's not me who downvoted sorry. My com is only for moderation purposes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0
for i in 0...10000 {
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 { 
        sum = sum + i
        print(i) 
    }
} 
print(sum)
```

Comment: Need `var` instead of let. `sum += i` is also preferable

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sum the resulting i like below

```
 var sum = 0

 for i in 0...10000 {
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 { 

      sum = sum + i
      print(i) 
    }
}
```

Now sum contains the Sum of the values

Answer (score 0):

In the Bottom line, this should to be working.

```
var sum = 0
for i in 0...10000 {
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 { 
        sum += i
        print(i)
    }
} 
print(sum)
```